# ERROR :: Could not find file ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, file

I want to read "file11.dat" from **any Location** on my hard drive, but it is not working.

It is followed by error shown below.

```
ERROR :: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\file11.dat'.
```

If I place a file at above location as specified it does not give me the error. Please help!

Comment: What code do you have? What's the exception message? Stack trace? What technology are you using? Where is the code running? Please answer at least all of these questions or the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @Elion : i will keep these Questions in mind for next time. Thanks for your valuable advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Server.MapPath("location");
```

It will take the file from your solution folder itself